# dbpedia sparql query returns 0 result

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I’m new to query languages and linked data so thanks a lot for the help. I also have a similar question about sparql on wikidata
[Wikidata sparql query returns 0 result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706339/wikidata-sparql-query-returns-0-result)

I would like to look up all the art movements in dbpedia with the associated artists (associated with the movement -peopleNam, famous for the movement-famousName,  influence the movement-influenceName) here is my query with lots of redundant prefix (that I could not enter because of the amount of links)

```
SELECT ?movementName ?famousName ?peopleName ?influenceName
        WHERE {
        ?m dc:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Art_movements> .
        ?m rdfs:label ?movementName .
        FILTER(LANG(?movementName) = "en")
        ?m dbp:knownFor ?a .
        ?a rdfs:label ?famousName .
        FILTER(LANG(?famousName) = "en")
        ?m dbp:movement ?b .
        ?b rdfs:label ?peopleName .
        FILTER(LANG(?peopleName) = "en")
        ?m dbp:influencedBy ?d .
        ?d rdfs:label ?influenceName .
        FILTER(LANG(?influenceName) = "en")
        }'
```

When I run the query with only the movement name I get 235 results but whenever I add any other artist name, I get 0 result. Could you show me what went wrong?

A similar query is done in wikidata with some encouraging results but I haven’t tried to match the two sources yet.

Thanks

Comment: Replace `dc:` with `dct:`; `dbp:` with `^dbo:` (3 times).

Comment: Right, wrong prefixes and wrong direction. "is <property> " in the web interface of a resource `r` indicates a triple `o <property> r`, i.e. incoming triples.

Comment: By the way, for completeness and to avoid prefix error, try to declare the prefixes in the beginning of the query - anything else can lead to problems when different tripe stores do have different built-in prefix mappings.

Comment: You should also use property paths for more compact queries: `PREFIX  dbo:  <http://www.dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX  dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>`

Comment: `SELECT ?m ?movementName ?famousName ?peopleName ?influenceName
        WHERE {

        ?m dct:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Art_movements> ;
           rdfs:label ?movementName ;
           ^dbo:knownFor/rdfs:label ?famousName ;
 ^dbo:movement/rdfs:label ?peopleName ;
^dbo:influencedBy/rdfs:label ?influenceName .

        FILTER(LANG(?movementName) = "en")
        FILTER(LANG(?famousName) = "en")
        FILTER(LANG(?peopleName) = "en")
        FILTER(LANG(?influenceName) = "en")
}`

Comment: Thank you so much to AKSW and Stanislav! I edited my question to include another sparql query on wikidata and explain that I couldn’t includ the prefix because I can’t post more than 8 links yet :)